# timedatectl: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, systemd, ntp

On my Yocto (Nanbield) based embedded Linux system, disabling NTP fails regularly.

```
$ timedatectl set-ntp false
```

The output is often (not always):

```
Failed to set ntp: Connection timed out
```

I would assume that disabling NTP does not need to access the network. So why it's a connection that times out.

Version: `systemd 254 (254.4^)`

I'm a bit stuck with debugging. I couldn't find any useful information in the logs (`journalctl`).

Any hints how to debug that issue?

Thanks!